# bi-directional and uni-directional associations UML

Tags: uml, associations

While I think I understand `aggregation` and `composition`, I am having difficulties understanding `bi-directional` and `uni-directional` association.
I've read that with `bi-directional` association, both classes know about
each other and with `uni-directional` association only one of the classes is aware
of the relationship. However this explanation seems too abstract for me and I would
like to know what this in particular means for my code and for the program I am writing.
It would be very nice if you could, along with explanation, provide a simple example
of how these two translate to code (I prefer c++, but it can be anything including pseudocode)

Comment: You have some examples in http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/change-bidirectional-association-to-unidirectional and http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+4.+Class+Diagrams+The+Essentials/Associations/.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Bi-directional associations are navigable from both ends. For instance, given the following classes (for simplicity, suppose that the association is 0..1 in both ends)

```
class Parent {
  Child* children;
}

class Child {
  Parent* parent;
}
```

you can go from a `Parent` to its child, and vice-versa: the parent knows about its child, the child knows about its parent, and (if `this.parent!=null`) `this.parent.child==this` (othewise it would not be the same association).

```
Parent <---------> Child
```

However, if there were no pointer to `Parent` in `Child`:

```
class Child { }
```

it would be an uni-directional association: you can go from parent to child, but you cannot go back from children to parent.

```
Parent ----------> Child
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the difference between `bi-directional` and `uni-directional` association, but now I have a second question.
So far I thought that having a member pointer/reference to the associated class would be an implementation of aggregation, but your code sample uses pointers too.
Does it mean that aggregation and association are implemented the same way in code?

Comment: Yes, aggregation is more like a conceptual element of the model. I remember we discussed about it in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285996/do-pointer-reference-data-members-indicate-an-association-or-aggregaation-relati/15294388

Comment: Ok, thanks very much, now it all starts to make much more sense to me.
So to summarize my findings:
association, aggregation and composition are rather semantic concepts
which can basically be implemented in very similar ways.
Additionaly (for all those that happen to come across this thread in future) I found this so post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298177/association-vs-aggregation, that clarifies the semantic differences between the three.

Comment: Now I know what, but I'm wonder the Why, it looks like there's no reason to uni-directional if you can bi-directional.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the UML specification does not define any concept of "bidirectional association", but only mentions "bidirectional navigability" where "navigability" (indicated with an *arrow* in a class diagram) does not have a well-defined computational meaning as it can be provided, e.g., by reference properties or by queries. The most efficient form of "navigability", provided by reference properties, is modeled with the UML concept of *association end ownership* (indicated with a *dot* in a class diagram).

***Bidirectional associations*** can be precisely defined as a pair of ***mutually inverse reference properties***. This definition implies two conditions:

1. for `this` referencing a child, `this.parent.child == this`, as explained in the somewhat incomplete answer of Javier, but in addition also
2. for `this` referencing a parent, `this.child.parent == this`.

You can read more about this, and find many class diagrams describing examples of bidirectional associations in the tutorials [Managing Bidirectional Associations in Java EE](http://web-engineering.info/tech/JavaJpaJsfApp/bidirectional-association-tutorial.html) and [Managing Bidirectional Associations in JavaScript](http://web-engineering.info/tech/JsFrontendApp/bidirectional-association-tutorial.html).